# C++ Get failure for process running in background

Tags: c++

I'm starting a script from my app and using & at the end of the command to run the process in the background:

```
std::string pCommand = "python myscript.py &";
int ret = system(pCommand.c_str());

if (ret == 0)
{
    //No error, continue...
}
```

However even if the script fails, the return from `system()` is always 0. If I remove the & so it does not run in the background, then I do get the correct exit code on failure.

Is there a way to detect if the process failed, or is that simply not possible when executing a background process with `system()`?

Comment: If you make something run in the background, then it hasn't returned, so there is no return code the system can give you.

Comment: Right, and that makes sense. But is there a way to get the return code once the process does exit, like having some sort of "listener" or something?

Comment: You can install a SIGCHLD handler and collect the exit code with `wait()`/`wait4()` when the child terminates.

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in the background, you check the value of ret before the script is over, and ret default value is probably 0.

Comment: Is there a way around this? How would the OP use it?

Comment: You could probably use a std::future that asynchrously check the state in a lambda function, or think about a full Python integration with Boost::Python